# The same cell in two uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cell, collectionview

I have extension ViewController : MainCollectionview, which I use to customize MainCollectionViewCell and CustomizeMainDescription cell.

In next steps, I want to create a collection view in another VC. The collection view cell will be same but have different data than MainVC. My question is how to use CustomizeMainDescription in this new collectionView?

This code shows part of my CustomizeMainDescription.

```
func levelCustomization(_ indexPath: IndexPath, _ cell: MainDishCollectionViewCell) {
    switch arrayDish[indexPath.row].level {
    case 1:
        setColourLvlCircle(cell)
        cell.buttonLvl1.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl2.setImage(circle, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl3.setImage(circle, for: .normal)
    case 2:
        setColourLvlCircle(cell)
        cell.buttonLvl1.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl2.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl3.setImage(circle, for: .normal)
    case 3:
        setColourLvlCircle(cell)
        cell.buttonLvl1.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl2.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
        cell.buttonLvl3.setImage(circleFill, for: .normal)
    default:
        print("nil")
    }
}
```

Comment: where is CustomizeMainDescription in your code? how do you want to use it?

Comment: To share cells between multiple table/collection views you have to use an extra XIB

Comment: CustomizeMainDescription is separate file. Now I used him to customize cell in maincollectionview and thats works, but when I added new view and new collection view i cant use method in customizemaincescription, because all func take parameter MaincollectionviewCell. I want use this func in other collectionview looks the same how Maincollectionview.

Comment: you can take as a parameter UICollectionViewCell as is your MaincollectionviewCell inherited UICollectionViewCell